# yii1 preventing sql injection

Tags: yii, sql-injection

I am using method:

> $model->attributes = $_POST['Booking'];

To load all my post data to model and using model for query

> Abc::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$model->abc_id));

I want to prevent my site from SQL injection.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If youre using ActiveRecord to handle DB requests (like in this case) - youre doing it good.

> Yii Query Builder offers an object-oriented method for building SQL queries, which helps reduce risk of SQL injection attacks.

If you want to read more about this, check this wiki [Yii Secure Application](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/)

Comment: I am using ActiveRecord to handle DB but still SQL injunction is possible on my site. is there any other way to prevent this  without using prepared statement?

Comment: Can you share code where the sql injection is possible? Because in case you posted here - it shouldnt.

Comment: well I am not sure about the exact place but found that there are unexpected data enter in db. So I just want to secure my site from all the way

Comment: Problem might be in `findAll()` method, if you use it like `->findAll("post_id = $postId)` - that's possible sql injection, otherwise it's validation rules. What is exacly this unwanted data enter in db?

Comment: "%&>#@dfg*(" this is entry DB which is expected to be id of about 5 digits

Comment: So the problem is not with sql injection, its wrong validation. First of all, column is not integer (if it has to be 5 digits - make this integer - database wont accept anything else than integer). Second - add validation rule to this attribute - Yii1 have an Number validator by default: [NumberValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/reference-model-rules-validation/#hh16)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147363/discussion-between-paritosh-mahale-and-yupik).